# Add an ID/variable from another item into current item and add to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, variables

I am creating a website with a CMS where you have 'Menucards' where you can put 'Categories' in. I am stuck on the process of adding the ID of the menucard into the database table of categories.

The way I thought would work was the following:

In the database the table of categories

```
create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "menucard_id"
end
```

In the menucards index:

```
<%= link_to("menucard", { :action => 'show', :id => menucard.id}) %>
```

which gives me an URL like this:  "http://localhost:3000/menucards/1"

This is the show of the menucard:

```
<%= link_to("Categorie toevoegen", 
    {:controller => 'categories', 
        :action => 'new', 
        :menucard_id => '@current_menucard'}, 
        :class => 'btn btn-green') 
%>
```

In the application_controller I defined current_menucard like this:

```
def current_menucard
    current_menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
end
```

If I press use the link_to from categories the URL is "http://localhost:3000/categories/new?menucard_id=%40current_menucard"

I see that using :menucard_id => '@current_menucard' is not really working. I'm stuck at this part.
Thanks for helping!

For further information:

categories_controller:

```
<div class="form-area">
<%= form_for([@category], :url => { :action => 'create'}, :html => { :id => "js-editor-page"}) do |category| %>
    <label for="name">
        <h2>Naam</h2>
        <%= category.text_field :name, :class => "full", :placeholder => "Wat is de naam van deze categorie?" %>
    </label>
    <%= category.hidden_field :menucard_id, :value => current_menucard %>
</div><!-- .form-area -->
<aside class="form-actions">
    <%= category.submit "Opslaan", :class => "btn btn-green" %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

I updated my code with the answer of MurifoX. Now the menucard_id is still not updated in the database. As you can see I use a hidden field to pass the value of current_menucard but it gives me the following:

```
Couldn't find Menucard without an ID
```

But later on in the errorpage I do get the correct parameters:

```
Parameters:

{"menucard_id"=>"67"}
```

Why isn't it being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :menucard_id

```
<%= link_to("Categorie toevoegen", 
{:controller => 'categories', 
    :action => 'new', 
    :menucard_id => '@current_menucard'}, 
    :class => 'btn btn-green') 
%>
```

to: :id

```
<%= link_to("Categorie toevoegen", 
{:controller => 'categories', 
    :action => 'new', 
    :id => '@current_menucard'}, 
    :class => 'btn btn-green') 
%>
```

and add this line in your categories controller new action:

```
@menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
```

Now you can work with the @menucard variable in your new category view and add the value into your hidden field. This should work

Answer (score 0):

Inside your application controller, define that you are using the method as a helper

```
helper_method :current_menucard
def current_menucard
  mc = Menucard.find(params[:id])
  mc.id
end
```

On your view, use the method that returns to you and integer

```
<%= link_to("Categorie toevoegen", 
 {:controller => 'categories', 
  :action => 'new', 
  :menucard_id => current_menucard}, 
  :class => 'btn btn-green') 
%>
```

I believe this may work.

Comment: Id did work to the point that it now picks the correct menucard_id. Only it is not being updated in the database. menucard_id is still NULL